# Sculpt Mode Blender 2.81 Object not visible

Tags: sculpt

When I switch to sculpt work-space, no object is being shown, the screen is blank, only two circles are visible, I hope they are the radius and strength circles. But the object is not visible. Any help is appreciated.[image: Object is not visible]